# Case Insensitive textbox match

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show user if the text entered match with another text box value

So i have written a jQuery function to check weather if entered value matched with the existing textbox value

```js
$('#password, #confirm_password').on('keyup', function() {
  if ($('#password').val() == $('#confirm_password').val()) {
    $('#message').html('Matching').css('color', 'green');
  } else
    $('#message').html('Not Matching').css('color', 'red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  text1 :
  <input name="password" id="password" type="text" value="ABC" />
</label>
<br>
<label>
  text2:
  <input type="text" name="confirm_password" id="confirm_password" /> 
</label>
<div id="message"></div>
```

I want the jquery to accept match even user entered without case sensitive matching

Comment: Convert both strings to the same case before comparison.

Comment: How does that make sense in the context of a password field?

Comment: `if ($('#password').val().toLowerCase() === $('#confirm_password').val().toLowerCase())`

Comment: If you match without it being case sensitive then it's not accurate, unless you want the password to be converted and be `non-case-sensitive`, which is much less secure.

Comment: While the question is valid from a JS perspective, isn't allowing your password/confirm password to be different going to cause you problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert both the values to lower case and then match.

```
  $('#password, #confirm_password').on('keyup', function() {
      if ($('#password').val().toLowerCase() == $('#confirm_password').val().toLowerCase()) {
        $('#message').html('Matching').css('color', 'green');
      } else
        $('#message').html('Not Matching').css('color', 'red');
    });
```

Comment: Dear downvoter, may I know the reason please :)?